# Java .where() in Android

Tags: java, android, java-8

I'm trying to port some Java code to Android. The code has a filter in it

```
Type underlyingType = new TypeToken<JsonResponse<T>>() { }
    .where(new TypeParameter<T>() { }, elementClass)
    .getType();
```

but the .where gives the following error in Android Studio 2.1.2

> Cannot resolve method 'where(anonymous com.google.common.reflect.TypeParameter<T>, com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken<T>`)'

What library is this where coming from? I've even tried [JDK8 with the Android N preview](https://developer.android.com/preview/j8-jack.html)

These are the imports in the class

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import org.apache.http.Header;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.config.RequestConfig;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.ContentType;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;
import org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.CloseableHttpAsyncClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.HttpAsyncClients;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicHeader;
import org.apache.http.nio.client.methods.HttpAsyncMethods;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import rx.Observable;
import rx.apache.http.ObservableHttp;
import rx.apache.http.ObservableHttpResponse;
import rx.functions.Func1;


import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Map;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;
import com.google.common.reflect.TypeParameter;
```

Comment: [Guava: `com.google.common.reflect.TypeToken`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/17.0/api/docs/?com/google/common/reflect/TypeToken.html)

Comment: Thank you @Holger! I think it was being hidden by the `import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken`

Comment: Why the down votes?

Answer (score 1):

Updated as per @Holger comment.

---

Use `com.google.common.reflect.TypeToken` instead `com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken` instead. That is `import com.google.common.reflect.TypeToken`.